# Defining the probability distribution function

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$ is a random variable that takes values in $[0,1].$ Is it that the probability distribution of $X$ is defined on $[0,1]$ or whole $R$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability distribution is defined on the whole of $\mathbb{R}$. Also, you need to understand that, this is given by an integral or sum depending on what $X$ is, whose limits are usually taken to be from $-\infty$ to $x \in \mathbb R$.

In general, any function $F$ is a distribution function if it satisfies the following properties:

- $0 \leq F(x) \leq 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$
- $F$ is a non-decreasing function of $x$.
- $F(-\infty) := \lim_{x \to -\infty}{F(x)}=0$ and $F(\infty) := \lim_{x \to \infty}{F(x)}=1$
- $F$ is right continuous, i.e. $F(x+)=F(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

And, it can be shown that, given $F$ with above properties, there exists a probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr A, P)$ on which a random variable $X$ exists  such that $X$ has $F$ as its distribution.

Comment: I think your requires for $F$ may be slightly circular.  There are distributions functions which are not defined on $\mathbb{R}$, such as those are defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and I see no reason why one cannot be defined on $[0.1]$

Comment: All I have said is for a one-dimensional random variable, $F$ is necessarily (by convention, if you like), defined on $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 0):

@Kannappan Sampath has given you all the properties of the distribution function but not really explained *what* the distribution function is or why it is defined for all $x$.  The value of the
distribution function $F(x)$ is the *probability* that the random variable
$X$ is no larger than $x$:

> For each $x, -\infty < x < \infty$, $F(x) = P\{X \leq x\}$.

For *every* random variable $X$, $F(x)$ is defined for all real numbers
$x$. Your particular $X$ takes on values between $0$ and $1$ only,
but we can still talk of $P\{X \leq 5\}$ and say that its value is $1$.
The general property that the *limit* of $F(x)$ is $1$ as $x \to \infty$
is perfectly true in this case, but it is also true that $F(x) = 1$ for
all $x \geq 1$, that is, the limiting value is not *approached*
asymptotically as $x \to \infty$ but is achieved (and held) from
$x=1$ onwards as we let $x \to \infty$.
Similarly for $\lim_{x \to -\infty} F(x) = 0$
which limiting value is not approached asymptotically.

Comment: This really answers the question!

Answer (score -1):

There is not a lot of difference.

With a probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr A, P)$, the sample space $\Omega$ must contain all possible events; whether it includes impossible ones too does not matter much so long as you are clear.

If the distribution is defined on the whole of $\mathbb{R}$ but values cannot be less than 0 or more than 1, then you can ignore both of these possibilities.  If you keep them then $\Pr(X\lt 0)=0$ and $\Pr(X\gt 1)=0$.